# How to resolve datafeeds error for backtesting using Backtrader and Python with local csv file?

Tags: python, oserror, backtrader

I am trying to build code for backtesting crypto strategy using backtrader and python but getting errors every time i try to connect data feeds, I tried different data feed methods and tried many other ways to connect but getting some or other kind of error every time, nothing seems to work. please help!

mentioned two methods I am trying to use in the code.

Code:

```
import backtrader as bt
import os
import sys
import datetime

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

#Method 1: YahooFinanceCSVData
modpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
datapath = os.path.join(modpath, 'C:/Users/admin/xx/xx2/xx.csv')
data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceCSVData(dataname=datapath, reverse=False)

#Method 2: GenericCSVData
data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData (dataname='filename.csv', dtformat=1)

cerebro.adddata(data)

cerebro.run()

cerebro.plot()
<end>
```

Data file's first string:
1623809640000,40124.02000000,40129.70000000,40100.00000000,40107.65000000,12.53749700,1623809699999,502950.08549781,339,4.72578400,189573.50347000,0

**#Errors
#Method 1 #ValueError month must be in 1..12
#Method 2 #OSError [Errno 22] Invalid argument**

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows:

> dtformat: Format used to parse the datetime CSV field. See the python strptime/strftime documentation for the format.
>
> If a numeric value is specified, it will be interpreted as follows
>
> 1: The value is a Unix timestamp of type int representing the number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970
>
> 2: The value is a Unix timestamp of type float

If you try to convert your datetime directly you get:

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = 1623809640000
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-2bb3006fc757> in <module>
      4 # if you encounter a "year is out of range" error the timestamp
      5 # may be in milliseconds, try `ts /= 1000` in that case
----> 6 print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

ValueError: year 53426 is out of range
```

This is because your datetime is in milliseconds. Correcting to seconds by dividing by 1000, you get:

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = 1623809640000 / 1000
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Resulting in:

```
"2021-06-16 02:14:00"
```

I believe this is probably the source of your problem.